# Site not displaying in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I have a problem displaying my site in IE, the site is [mysite](http://www.hairochnuvarberg.se).
If you check the source code you can see that the site contains html but NOTHING is displayed, i have removed all javascripts and it still doesnt work. What has IE done 2014 for this to happen?

Comment: Paste your problem areas in the question.

Comment: Your source code shows a lot of &. Use &amp; instead.

Comment: Please use a browser :p just kidding, no offences to anyone :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this to debug your code: [W3 Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.hairochnuvarberg.se/&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

Try changing the `&` to `&amp;`

Comment: This did it. Strange that they changed that overnight

Comment: it seems that the reference to google maps api couldnt have & in the link either.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem is caused by having an unencoded ampersand in your title element. It seems that Chrome is able to figure this out, but IE just dies.

It is setting the title element as blank, and not trying to render anything else.